# How to set a color tag from one file to the corresponding one in macOS?

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan, tags

I have a bunch of a few hundred files that have been converted to an other file format, let's say GIFs to JPG. The GIFs were color tagged and now I want to give the same tags from the GIFs to the corresponding JPG files. But I have no clue what's the way to go here.

I have installed the cli tool "tag" via MacPorts but struggled to build a chain with "find" to do what I need. I'm tool agnostic - whatever does the job is welcome whether it's bash, an app or AppleScript...

Any hints for me? Thanxx a lot!

Comment: Google(ExifTools)? Never tried it on GIFs though.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I should have been more exact in my description. The files are "tagged" with macOS finder color tags, not that kind of tags used by ExifTool or used with MP3s. I think it's a kind of exteded attribute for files. The color tags could be used to mark all files for a project or be used as a ranking or "red" should be deleted while green should be kept, etc...

Comment: I found a bash script on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720376/how-can-i-add-os-x-tags-to-files-programmatically) but with my few shell scripting capabilities I'm not able to adopt this to my problem :-(((

Answer (score 0):

So, after heavy trial and error testing it seems that I got a working one-liner :-P

It requires the installation of the shell tool "[tag](https://github.com/jdberry/tag)" (e.g. via HomeBrew or MacPorts)

```
for i in `find -E . -iregex ".*\.(gif|bmp|png)"` ; do FILE=$(tag -l $i | awk '{print $1}' | awk '{print substr($0, 0, length($0) - 4)}') ; TAG=$(tag -l $i | awk '{print $2}') ; find . -name "$FILE*.jpg" -exec tag -s "$TAG" {} \; ; done
```

I hope this is of any use for somebody else...

Comment: Hmpf... It seems that there can be issues if your machine is not runnig in English. Mine is set to German so the tag "Yellow" is "Gelb" here but the script sets the tag "Yellow" to the converted file which has no color...